# Comprimir una carpeta completa en Zip e ingresar el nombre de cual carpeta sera comprimida. JAVA

Tags: java, zip

Estoy haciendo un programa que comprime en zip el archivo que se le indica, pero no me comprime la carpetas, solamente archivos individuales y lo que me interesa es comprimir carpetas,  tambien quisiera saber como el programa pida el nombre de la carpeta que se tiene que comprimir y no tener que ingresarlo en el codigo de uno por uno.

Anexo el codigo que llevo:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;

public class Conversor {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // cadena que contiene la ruta donde están los archivos a comprimir
        String directorioZip = "C:\\ZIP\\";
        // ruta completa donde están los archivos a comprimir
        File carpetaComprimir = new File(directorioZip);

        // valida si existe el directorio
        if (carpetaComprimir.exists()) {
            // lista los archivos que hay dentro del directorio
            File[] ficheros = carpetaComprimir.listFiles();


            // ciclo para recorrer todos los archivos a comprimir
            for (int i = 0; i < ficheros.length; i++) {
                System.out.println("Nombre del fichero: " + ficheros[i].getName());
                String extension="";
                for (int j = 0; j < ficheros[i].getName().length(); j++) {
                    //obtiene la extensión del archivo
                    if (ficheros[i].getName().charAt(j)=='.') {
                        extension=ficheros[i].getName().substring(j, (int)ficheros[i].getName().length());
                        //System.out.println(extension);
                    }
                }
                try {
                    // crea un buffer temporal para ir poniendo los archivos a comprimir
                    ZipOutputStream zous = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(directorioZip + ficheros[i].getName().replace(extension, ".zip")));

                    //nombre con el que se va guardar el archivo 
                    ZipEntry entrada = new ZipEntry(ficheros[i].getName());
                    zous.putNextEntry(entrada);



                        //obtiene el archivo para comprimir
                        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(directorioZip+entrada.getName());
                        int leer;
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                        while (0 < (leer = fis.read(buffer))) {
                            zous.write(buffer, 0, leer);
                        }
                        fis.close();
                        zous.closeEntry();
                    zous.close();                   
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }               
            }
            System.out.println("Directorio de salida: " + directorioZip);
        } else {
            System.out.println("No se encontró el directorio..");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo utilizo zip4j una librería código abierto que realiza todo lo necesario en cuanto a zip, la recomiendo plenamente, también permite cifrar con contraseña, etc. http://www.lingala.net/zip4j/

Para comprimir una carpeta (y todo lo que contenga... sin tener que trabajar la recursividad) basta con:

```
String pathZipInput = "C:/..."; // carpeta a comprimir
String pathOutputZip = "C:/..."; // ruta y nombre del zip que se genera
try {
    ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(pathOutputZip);               
    ZipParameters parameters = new ZipParameters();
        parameters.setCompressionMethod(Zip4jConstants.COMP_DEFLATE);
        parameters.setCompressionLevel(Zip4jConstants.DEFLATE_LEVEL_NORMAL);
        parameters.setEncryptFiles(true);
        parameters.setEncryptionMethod(Zip4jConstants.ENC_METHOD_AES);
        parameters.setAesKeyStrength(Zip4jConstants.AES_STRENGTH_256);        
    zipFile.addFolder(pathZipInput, parameters); 
    // en la linea superior cambiar Folder por File si es archivo o carpeta
} catch (ZipException e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: " + e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

En mi humilde opinión, lo mejor para zip que hay, no sé si será la respuesta que buscar pero hecharle un ojo.

Comment: Muchas gracias enseguida lo checo, y para que el usuario le ingrese el nombre de la carpeta que sera comprimida se te ocurre algo, agradezco tu ayuda.

Comment: Muchas gracias, eso hare y comento que tal me funciono.